# Using transient property in findBy or listOrderBy methods

Tags: hibernate, grails, dns

I have a domain class using some transient property foo. Now I want to use listOrderByFoo on this property but I get the error "could not resolve property: foo".
Is there any way to use transient properties in listOrderByProperty() or findByProperty() ?

```
class Bar {
 String name
 static transients = ['foo']
 def getFoo() {
   ...
 }
}

Bar.findAllByFooIsNotNull()
Bar.listOrderByFoo()
```

Comment: Transient properties are, by definition, not persisted. How can you expect to query on properties which Hibernate is basically told to ignore?

Comment: As transient properties are mostly something calculated I thought I could use them like a defined variable in a sql statement (e.g. COUNT(*) as number)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately no. Like Matt said in his comment to your question, since those fields are marked as transient, they are not persisted to the database and thus there's no way for you to query them. If you want to find or list by a transient property, you'll need to write a closure to iterate over a list of objects with the transient property already set. There's no dynamic GORM method that you can use to do it.

```
def bars = [ new Bar(foo:1), new Bar(foo:2), new Bar(foo:4), new Bar(foo:3) ];

// Find bar with foo=3
bars.find { it.foo == 3 }

// Sort bars by foo
bars.sort { a,b -> a.equals(b)? 0: a.foo<b.foo? -1: 1 }
```