# Derived field in GORM utilizing mapped owner's fields

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to figure out how to make a derived boolean field in my domain class. The boolean field is derived from comparison to the mapped owner's values. Is this possible in GORM? I've tried it quite a few different ways and I keep getting various SQL errors. My domain classes are below:

```
class Reading {
    float readingValue
    Date dateCreated
    boolean alarmedState

    static constraints = {
        readingValue(nullable: false)
    }  

    static belongsTo = [sensor : Sensor]

    static mapping = {
        autoTimestamp true
        sort "dateCreated"
        alarmedState formula: "(READING_VALUE < SENSOR.ALARM_IF_LESS) || (READING_VALUE > SENSOR.ALARM_IF_GREATER)"
    }

}

class Sensor {

    String description
    String location
    SensorType typeEnum
    double alarmIfGreater
    double alarmIfLess

    static hasMany = [readings : Reading]
    static constraints = {
        alarmIfGreater(nullable: true)
        alarmIfLess(nullable: true)
        description(blank: false)
        location(blank: false)
        typeEnum(blank: false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [transients](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/transients.html) property might do what you want. E.g.

```
class Reading {
    float readingValue
    Date dateCreated

    static constraints = {
        readingValue(nullable: false)
    }  

    static belongsTo = [sensor : Sensor]
    static transients = ['alarmedState']

    static mapping = {
        autoTimestamp true
        sort "dateCreated"
        //alarmedState formula: "(READING_VALUE < SENSOR.ALARM_IF_LESS) || (READING_VALUE > SENSOR.ALARM_IF_GREATER)"
    }

    Boolean getAlarmedState() {
        ( readingValue < sensor.alarmIfLess || readingValue > sensor.alarmIfGreater )
    }
}
```

I've not tested this code but it might get you on the right track...

Comment: I tried this. Unfortunately it seems you can't query by transients. See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022684/using-transient-property-in-findby-or-listorderby-methods)

Comment: Did you try changing your formula to use traditional SQL, with a select and where clauses?

Comment: That's right, `formula` needs to be valid, backend-specific SQL. If you enable SQL logging, you will see what kind of query is being constructed.