# GORM: Query having subquery empty

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Scenario:

I have two domain beans Book and Author.
Author has a one-to-many association with Book.

I want authors who NOT have written books in this year (it isn't the real scenario :) )

This is my MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM author AS a
WHERE 
(SELECT COUNT(b.id)
    FROM book AS b
    WHERE b.author_id = a.id
    AND b.releaseDate > '2014-01-01'
) = 0
```

How can I convert it to a **Hibernate/Grails criteria**?

**Edit:**

- More explicit: I need the equivalent Grails criteria.
- I have many book and author records. Gorm query must be high performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved, but not using criteria.
I used HQL:

```
def authors = Author.findAll("\
SELECT * FROM author AS a \
WHERE \
(SELECT COUNT(b.id) \
    FROM a.books AS b \
    WHERE b.releaseDate > '2014-01-01' \
) = 0")
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you; it may be a little slow due to the sorting, however if your number of books is relatively small, it shouldn't have a huge impact.

```
def targetDate = // define your date here.
def lazyAuthors = Author.findAll{
   books.sort{it.requestDate}[books.size()-1] > targetDate
}
```

****EDIT**** It turns out you can't query transients so my original thought would not work, however the technique I used to get the latest book should work.

Comment: I try it but Grails says:
No signature of method: grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria.mostRecentBook() is applicable for argument types: ... (closure)

But, even if it works, I worry for performance :/

Comment: [About transients property in query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022684/using-transient-property-in-findby-or-listorderby-methods)

Comment: Well, I feel sheepish, I'll modify my answer to reflect this info.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the time now to test the answer, but based on my understanding of the queries etc.. this should work properly.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I have many book and author records (my fault: I don't specified it in my question; I edit it). 
However I resolved using HQL (see my answer).