# Grails: How to search a key word in encrypted column and get rows

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-domain-class, grails-2.1

I am working on an grails application where it can save SMS or email in the database. These messages are saved in an encrypted format.

I am trying to get rows from the table by using keyword search criteria. As this is encrypted, I am not able to find a query which can search with a keyword.

I have tried adding the `transients` to domain class and decrypt it. Here is the code:

in domain class:

```
 static transients = ['decrypted']

 String getDecrypted() {
     return DESCodec.decryptText(message)
 }
```

and

```
 def m2 = Messages.findAll {-1 == it.getDecrypted().indexOf("xyz")};
```

which did not work.

Can someone tell me if there is a way to get rows by searching using a keyword in the encrypted column?

Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you read this [Using transient property in findBy or listOrderBy methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022684/using-transient-property-in-findby-or-listorderby-methods).

Basically a transient object becomes available when you have an object to hand. So writing hql/hibernate queries will not really work. You may have better luck doing something like:

```
def m2 = Messages.findAll {-1 == DESCodec.decryptText(it.message).contains("xyz")};
```

Unsure on above for sure, something you need to play around

Here is what you are trying to do

```
def listing = Messages.executeQuery("from Messages" ,[:],[max:-1])
def found = listing.findAll {-1 == it.decrypted.contains("xyz")};
```

or manually :

```
  def listing = Messages.executeQuery("select new map(id as id, message as message) from Messages" ,[:],[max:-1])
    def found = listing.findAll {-1 == DESCodec.decryptText(it.message).contains("xyz")};
```

Comment: thank you for your sugggestion. When I tired the code, I am getting back an error saying `No signature of method: static security.DESCodec.decryptText() is applicable for argument types: (grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria) values: [grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria@98e98f]`

Comment: you will need to experiment. when you have the objects it has the decrypted value so maybe `Messages.findAll().findAll {-1 == it.decrypted.indexOf("xyz")};`  a double findAll unsure if this works in later grails. But a query to get all objects then to check through collection is the key. the downside is obviously having to collect all data

Comment: yes, that's the reason. Collecting all the data would slow down the process.